# How to not make the text field clickable when it is in read-only in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui text field and it is in read-only mode. But the text-field still highlights when clicked on it. How to disable clickable when it is in read-only mode?

Answer (score -2):

use the attribute `disabled`

This link can be helpul for you: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/